# Sitecore Application access denied

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

We've just taken over a site based in Sitecore and the Windows Event Log is showing exceptions occurring whenever someone is logged into the admin.

Anybody know how to fix this? It looks like their missing a permission for something but I can't work out what I'd need to do to fix it.

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: AccessDeniedException 
    Exception message: Application access denied.
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.HasAccess(Boolean accessAllowed, String message)
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.CanRunApplication(String application)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.SITENAME.com/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingFieldDetails.aspx?db=master&id={31D7150F-352B-4800-8FDF-C90CDAD17D67}&la=en&vs=7&di=1&fld={B0A67B2A-8B07-4E0B-8809-69F751709806}&scDisabled=true 
    Request path: /sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingFieldDetails.aspx 
    User host address: 195.138.205.241 
    User: sitecore\USERNAME 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 136 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.HasAccess(Boolean accessAllowed, String message)
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.CanRunApplication(String application)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.TrackingField.TrackingFieldDetailsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it seems to be related to DMS. So there might be some code trying to update some tracking information or it might just be Sitecore that can't access it. It would probably be easier to have Sitecore Support look at it.

Comment: Have you checked the folder permissions (in Windows) to make sure the NETWORK SERVICE account has modify permissions as specified in the [installation guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/installation_guide_sc65-a4.pdf). It may be worth resetting them just to be sure something isn't missed.

Comment: The "HasAccess" method is how Sitecore checks item permissions. It looks like when the user tries to run the analytics application, you're running into Sitecore permissions issues on the application item. The app would be under core:/sitecore/content/applications/analytics.

Comment: I am getting this with an Approver role (custom created) in Sitecore however Don't get it with an admin role. but still not quite sure what access exactly is responsible for this

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to some of your recent configuration changes.
Do an IIS Reset or Restart your machine.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a security related issue with the web server hosting your site.

```
Open the IIS manager in the server 
Select your site 
Go to its advanced settings 
Under Process model, change the value of the field Identity to Network Service

If you are still experiencing a problem, open the command prompt and enter:
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" /add "NETWORK SERVICE"

This will give more access to the sitecore user in the server
```

Answer (score 0):

These sitecore knowledge base links may help, as the stack traces look very similar.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/848772

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/000050

Pulled from this post: http://www.seanholmesby.com/sitecore-accessdeniedexception-in-the-content-editor/